# An Inventor's Revenge

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Christopher is reasonably upset. The invention that has brought him the most glory and fame has come under attack, and more and more people have started using a very similar invention. To express his frustration, he distributed an encoded message, that only people using his invention would be able to interpret.

Here's the message:

```
DSXCE/RVY/UTBMU/CETGDB/CTBGF/WXSESC/ZM/XRVYN/TBNY/YRFHNV/MUYI/XN/TECDF/VYNHG/BVR/YNM/.
```

**What does the encoded message say?**

Do you have the means to interpret it? Or are you a traitor to Christopher's vision?

It may help knowing *what* Christopher invented, but alas, that would reveal too much to make this puzzle any challenge, though I will confidently say that, if you're reading this, you have probably already used his (or his competitor's) invention today.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Full answer: I suspect Christopher is

> Christopher Latham Sholes,

who invented

> the QWERTY keyboard.

And so

> The letters given describe shapes on the QWERTY keyboard, approximating "dVORAK_MUST_FALL".

Unfortunately,

> Sholes' QWERTY layout is not identical to the modern one; C and X are transposed, and M appears one row up on the far right. With Sholes' own layout, some of the glyphs would be garbled.

Comment: FWIW I came to the same conclusion :-).

Comment: can you clarify "describe shapes", maybe working through the transformation of the first few characters of the clue into the first character of your spoilered phrase?

Comment: (My "same conclusion" was only the bit Sneftel had posted when I wrote the above, namely identifying who Christopher was. I hadn't got the rest of it.)

Comment: After reading your great answer, I'm laughing at the massive hint in the OP's username! :-)

Comment: [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard) helps to give a little context to the solution. (Obviously spoiler-y!)